# Technique for reusing calculation class with different data sets

Tags: c#

I have ten different data sets which I need to perform the same calculations for, but each data set has different properties to compute these calculations off of.  Other than passing the property name as a string to the calculation function, is there another/better technique to select the appropriate property to perform the calculation in C#?  The example data sets are in JSON for demonstration purposes, the real code would work with List.  In the example below I'm calculating various stats based off of various "weight" properties.  The data types per class implementation are the same, but their property names differ.  Is there a cleaner / type-safe method for accomplishing this?  Passing a property string seems hacky.

```
// Data set 1
// var cars = new List<Car>();
[
  {carWeight: 5, ...},
  {carWeight: 6, ...},
  {carWeight: 4, ...}
]
```

```
// Data set 2
// var peope = new List<People>();
[
  {weight: 5, ...},
  {weight: 6, ...},
  {weight: 4, ...}
]
```

```
public Statistics GetStatistics<T>(List<T> list, string propertyName){
    var stats = new Statistics();

    var valuesToCalculate = list.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null);
    stats.Sum = valuesToCalculate.Sum();
    stats.Median = valuesToCalculate.Median();
    // ... More calculations

    return stats;
}
```

```
var carStats = GetStatistics<Car>(carList, "carWeight");
var peopleStats = GetStatistics<People>(peopleList, "weight");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression as property accessor. This is much faster than reflection and it is type safe.

```
public static Statistics GetStatistics<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, double> getValue)
{
    var stats = new Statistics();

    var valuesToCalculate = list.Select(getValue);
    stats.Sum = valuesToCalculate.Sum();
    stats.Median = valuesToCalculate.Median();
    // ... More calculations

    return stats;
}
```

Usage

```
var carStats = GetStatistics(carList, c => c.carWeight);
var peopleStats = GetStatistics(peopleList, p => p.weight);
```

Note: when calling `GetStatistics<T>(...)`, C# can infer the type parameter `T` from the type of the lists (`List<Car>` and `List<People>`).

I changed the type of the input paramter from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` as this makes the method more versatile. You could use an array as input or a filtered expression like

```
var carStats = GetStatistics(carList.Where(c => c.Brand == "BMW"), c => c.carWeight);
```

See: [Lambda expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)